# Sync RDBMS with Apache Directory Ldap

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ldap, spring-cloud-dataflow

Currently, I am on a requirement to sync data from apache direcotry ldap to any of the RDBMS Databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL). Directory approximately holds a ***few million*** of records for now and may grow in future. Ldap directory is being the primary data source for now but the motive is to have real time data in both Ldap as well as in RDBMS since We have a plan to use RDBMS for real-time analytics purpose.

**Option1:**
Thinking of using spring cloud data flow. A source spring boot app to read ldap data that are changed after the last sync run. Source app pushes data to queue(RabbitMQ for now). Sink would be another spring boot app that collects data directly from queue and persists the data into RDBMS. We will be able to better track and manage the sync process jobs using spring cloud data flow dashboard offerings.

**Option2:**
Spring LdapTemplate helps us to talk to ldap directory in our application. One approach would be to intercept the ldapTemplate calls wherever applicable and push the data to queue and then an intermediate app reads data from queue(RabbitMQ) and converts the ldap response to the required format that can be updated into RDBMS DB.

I am new to Ldap and spring cloud data flow. So far, I have got only these 2 approaches considering my project's existing technology and system landscape. Any other suggestions/ approach are really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One another approach if LDAP is Microsoft ad server then  creating windows service in C# which will connect to your LDAP server and fetch data every day and send data to your rdbms through socket connection. Which is reliable and consistent.

Comment: Thanks Sreekanth. We use Apache directory on Linux. I will check.